# ArcText.JS Throwing errors in HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to use the ArcText.JS jQuery plugin on my website to arc some text.

I have this error in my console on the page:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I have ArcText.JS declared in the head tag just before it closes.

```
    <!-- ArcText.JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>


<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Then in the body tag I have:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        $('#Services').arctext({radius: 300});
    });
</script>
```

Which is linked to a div:

```
    <div class="Services" id="Services">
    <div class="row text-vcenter">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="services">P1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="services">P2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="services">P3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my custom.css I do already have #Services styled but that shouldn't throw a JS error right?

**EDIT**

I edited the code to the following. Still no cigar.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Services').arctext({radius: 300});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dandapereira said in this post: [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

I changed `$(document).ready(function() {` to `window.onload = function(){` and it seems to be working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `jquery` in you page.

Comment: Its in there I guess I just didn't mention that it was initialized at the bottom of my page with `<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Could it possibly be because im trying to initialize the plugin before jQuery is even initialized? I thought `$(document).ready` made sure to wait to initialize anything before it was loaded.

Comment: @  Will have you included the reference of `Arctext.js ` after `jquery`??

Comment: I have solved my own question and marked it as the answer. Thanks for the help however.